# JavaFx WebView Storing and Manipulating Session Cookies of HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, post, cookies, webview, httpurlconnection

I'm writing an Java Desktop app which has different HTTP connections to the same website running through different proxies all in different threads. These threads are all posting to one website using an HttpURLConnection but are intended to appear as different users, all with different session cookies. I have written a basic cookie manager to allow each thread to have different sessions, by iterating through the http response headers and storing those with the key "Set-Cookie". The relevant code is below:

```
private void addCookie(String cookie) { //adds received cookie to cookie string
    if (cookies.contains(cookie)) return; //we have this exact cookie

    processor.printSys("New Cookie: " + cookie);
    cookies += (cookie + "; "); //add the new cookie followed by a semicolon
}

private void storeCookies(URLConnection con) { //iterates through headers, adding new cookies
    String headerName = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < con.getHeaderFields().size(); i ++) { //print headers for analysis
        System.out.println(con.getHeaderFieldKey(i) + ": " + con.getHeaderField(i));    
    }


    for (int i=1; (headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) addCookie(con.getHeaderField(i));               
}

private void setCookies(URLConnection conn) { //add stored cookies to next HttpURLConnection
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", ""); return;}

    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
    processor.printSys("Cookies Set: " + cookies);
}
```

This cookie manager was working flawlessly before and would properly store cookies, printing to the console the below text for each thread when `storeCookies(con)` was called.

```
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2016 20:57:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 977
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-XHR-Current-Location: /shop/169618/add
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "3a5199771b11612b34cba523cd4af312"
Set-Cookie: cart=FOO; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT
Set-Cookie: pure_cart=BAR; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT
Set-Cookie: _supreme_session=BAZ; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 20ef370b74e478b6484bb8d507a33a3a
X-Runtime: 0.021299
X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 2380939932
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Order 1: New Cookie: cart=FOO; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT (3:57:16 PM)
Order 1: New Cookie: pure_cart=BAR; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT (3:57:16 PM)
Order 1: New Cookie: _supreme_session=BAZ; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT; HttpOnly (3:57:16 PM)
```

However, I implemented a JFX WebView in my UI in a different thread an instantly noticed a change. All threads were storing the same session cookies and even when I explicitly set the cookies to be blank this was overridden. The WebView was implemented as shown below

```
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.setZoom(.5);
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
    });
```

This WebView would cause the same `storeCookies(con)` call to print:

```
null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2016 20:57:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 977
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-XHR-Current-Location: /shop/169618/add
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "3a5199771b11612b34cba523cd4af312"
Set-Cookie: cart=FOO; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT
Set-Cookie: pure_cart=BAR; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT
Set-Cookie:
X-Request-Id: 20ef370b74e478b6484bb8d507a33a3a
X-Runtime: 0.021299
X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 2380939932
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Order 1: New Cookie: cart=FOO; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT (3:57:16 PM)
Order 1: New Cookie: pure_cart=BAR; path=/; expires=Mon, 11-Jan-2016 20:57:16 GMT (3:57:16 PM)
Order 1: New Cookie:
```

Upon packet analysis with WireShark I determined these fields weren't blank, the _supreme_session cookie was still there it just could no longer be accessed in Java. Even worse, the session cookie of the JFX WebView was being passed in as the session cookie for every thread posting through HttpUrlConnection. Clearly something is going on in the background and overriding my cookie manager, setting and storing all cookies for any HttpURLConnection. When I comment out the WebView the issue is solved, so I just need to know what is going on in the background and how to disable it. Thanks, Ben